# TS errors when trying to use props inside styled-component

Tags: typescript, styled-components

I am using styled-components with type-script, and actually read [docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#typescript). When it is simple styling, without using props - all goes right:

```
interface IButtonWithIcon {
  children: string,
  type?: string,
  size?: number,
}

const ButtonWithIcon = styled<IButtonWithIcon, 'button'>('button')`
  color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
`;
```

But when I try, even to simply log props to console, like this:

```
const ButtonWithIcon = styled<IButtonWithIcon, 'button'>('button')`
  ${console.log}
  color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
`;
```

TS starts complaining:

> Argument of type '{ (message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]): void;
>   (message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]): voi...' is not assignable
>   to parameter of type 'Interpolation'.   Type '{ (message?: any,
>   ...optionalParams: any[]): void; (message?: any, ...optionalParams:
>   any[]): voi...' is not assignable to type 'ReadonlyArray |
>   Interpolat...'.
>       Property 'concat' is missing in type '{ (message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]): void; (message?: any, ...optionalParams:
>   any[]): voi...'.

If I add anotation, the error message changes:

```
const ButtonWithIcon = styled<IButtonWithIcon, 'button'>('button')`
${(props: IButtonWithIcon): void => console.log(props)}
color: black;
border-radius: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
`;
```

> Argument of type '(props: IButtonWithIcon) => void' is not assignable
>   to parameter of type 'Interpolation>'.   Type '(props: IButtonWithIcon) => void' is not assignable
>   to type 'ReadonlyArray | Interpolat...'.
>       Property 'concat' is missing in type '(props: IButtonWithIcon) => void'.

What is wrong in code below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions that you interpolate into the CSS must return something.  Try:

```
const ButtonWithIcon = styled<IButtonWithIcon, 'button'>('button')`
  ${(props) => { console.log(props); return ""; }}
  color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
`;
```